# How to run an url in google chrome using variables in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Hello I am new and learning shell commands. When I try it as single line command it works but when I store command and path into two variables and call it doesnt work.

```
google-chrome /home/bashscripts/index.html
```

OUTPUT : chrome opens /home/bashscripts/index.html **(WORKS)**

**What I want to achieve this through variables:**

```
A="google-chrome"
B="/home/bashscripts/index.html"

$C= echo $(eval $A) $B **(DOESNOT WORK)**
echo $C
```

OUTPUT: bash opens google-chrome blank new tab but html file is not opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
#!/bin/bash

A="google-chrome"
B="/home/bashscripts/index.html"

"$A" "$B"
```

However, I'd recommend not storing commands (like `google-chrome`) in variables; it can be done for simple commands like this, but [tends to fail for complex commands](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Variables are for data (like fienames), not for executable commands. Also, lower- or mixed-case variable names are generally safer to use, since there are a bunch of all-caps names with special meanings, and you can run into trouble if you accidentally use one of those for something else.

Everything else in your script is unnecessarily complex, and most is done wrong:

- To store something in a variable, use `varname=$(command)`, not `$varname=  command` -- the `$` and the space after `=` both change the meaning of the comamnd, and you need `$( )` to capture the output of the command.
- Also, you should almost never use `$(echo something)`, since the `echo` and `$( )` basically cancel each other out.
- And you shouldn't capture the output of a command without good reason. If you're just going to print the output (e.g. `echo $C`), then just skip capturing it and let it print directly.
- When you do need to print a variable, or actually use it in almost any context, you should put double-quotes around it to avoid weird parsing (e.g. `echo "$C"` instead of `echo $C`).
- Don't use `eval` unless you're an expert at how shell parsing works. It's basically an invitation to bizarre parsing bugs, and almost never actually necessary.

Finally, I recommend running your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), since it will point out many common scripting mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Your script should be:

```
A="google-chrome"
B="/home/bashscripts/index.html"
C=$(eval $A $B) 
echo "$C"
```

tldp: [Variable Assignment](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html)